# Having issues in installing a windows Service created using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services

I am trying to install a  windows Service created using Visual Studio 2010 on my local machine and on a Windows Server 2008 r2. I am getting the proper success reslt when I install it using the InstallUtil.exe Please find the below command line comments when I have installed the Service.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe
>   E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe Microsoft (R) .NET Framework
>   Installation utility Version 4.0.30319.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved. Running a transacted installation.
>   Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe assembly's
>   progress. The file is located at
>   E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService\MyService.InstallLog. Installing
>   assembly 'E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe'. Affected parameters
>   are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService\MyService.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe Installing service Service1... Service Service1 has been successfully installed. Creating EventLog
>   source Service1 in log Application... The Install phase completed
>   successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning. See the contents of
>   the log file for the E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe assembly's
>   progress. The file is located at
>   E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService\MyService.InstallLog. Committing
>   assembly 'E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe'. Affected parameters
>   are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService\MyService.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = E:\SomeFolder\MyService\MyService.exe The Commit phase completed successfully. The transacted install has completed.

but the problem is when I go to AdministrativeTools-->Services and try to start the installed service it gives the below error

> Services Windows could not start the MyServiceInstaller service on
>   Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start
>   or control request in a timely fashion. OK

Please let me know what should I do to start the server ??

Regards
Srividhya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some code for logging in service and check for errors in the log file. There is some code that is giving error. This code executes on `OnStart` event of the service.

Check the event viewer for more details under administrative tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... yes I checked and I had commented the code and deployed ... dont know how did I miss it ... Thanks